# Preg match all in pcre c++

Tags: c++, pcre, pcregrep

Hello this is my string

```
last_name, first_name
bjorge, philip
kardashian, kim
mercury, freddie
```

in `php` i am using `preg_match_all` (`pcre`) to start `regex` process

```
preg_match_all("/(.*), (.*)/", $input_lines, $output_array);
```

now i installed pcre on c++ and i want to know what exactly process in c++ pcre that equal my php code? what exactly function in c++ pcre that work like php `preg_match_all` ?

Comment: The instructions are here: http://www.pcre.org/pcre.txt look at the bottom under `pcrecpp` for the `C++` API.

Answer (score 0):

In C++ 11 regular expressions are supported by standard library. So you don't need to use pcre without any specific reasons.

As for example above, you can achieve the same using standard regular expressions. E.g.:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>

int main()
{
  std::vector<std::string> input = {
    "last_name, first_name",
    "bjorge, philip",
    "kardashian, kim",
    "mercury, freddie"
  };

  std::regex re("(.*), (.*)");
  std::smatch pieces;

  for (const std::string &s : input) {
    if (std::regex_match(s, pieces, re)) {
      std::cout << "Pieces: " << pieces.size() << std::endl;
      for (size_t i = 0; i < pieces.size(); ++i) {
        std::cout << pieces[i].str() << std::endl;
      }
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: i know it and i try it. but i think pcre is faster and i want to use it. im already use default regex ....

Comment: Just curious, how much is faster?

Comment: So much faster that I want to write my project with (on heavy process)

Comment: Yep, found this link http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/background_information/performance/section_Testing_Perl_searches_platform_linux_compiler_GNU_C_version_5_1_0_.html

std::regex still have to be improved :)